# Android call log latest entry

Tags: android, logging, call

I want to start an activity once i get a missed call.but iam unable to read the latest missed call entry from the call log, instead it reads the entry before the current one. iam reading it when phone state is idle.

Example: say there are two missed call entries one at 11:10 and other at 11:11. I get a missed call at 12:12, my activity needs to show missed calls obtained at 12:12,11:11,11:10. but rather it reads 11:11,11:10. Latest entry is missing. what should i do? I am using a service and reading call log, phone state.

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(allCalls, null, null, null, order); 
  if (c.moveToFirst()) { 
    do{ 
      // getting number,type,ack etc} 
    while (c.moveToNext()); }
```

Comment: how are you reading the missed call entries?

Comment: we'll need to see the code you're using, maybe there's a small bug causing the first one to be missed.

Comment: using a cursor..Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(allCalls, null, null, null, order);..i am using moveToFirst boolean to read from first entry.

Comment: Click "edit" in the lower left of your question to add your relevant code and logcat errors to the question.

Comment: Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(allCalls, null, null, null, order);
   
          if (c.moveToFirst())
          {
           
             do{ // getting number,type,ack etc} while (c.moveToNext()); reading this on phone state idle as of now

Comment: no errors in logcat, i am toasting the entries and unable to find the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to listen for it using [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) and [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html).

This code will show you how to do it:

```
if(lastStart == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING)
{
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long duration = (now-ringStartTime)/1000;
    bindService.AddMissCallInfo(ringPhoneNumber, ringStartTime, duration);
    Log.i(Constants.Tag,"service add miss call!");
}
```

> Code taken from: http://code.google.com/p/android-miss-call/source/browse/trunk/src/com/call/DialPhoneStateListener.java?r=3

Answer (score 0):

you can used like this.

```
      c=mContext.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, CallLog.Calls._ID + " DESC");
      if(c.getCount()!=0){
                c.moveToFirst();
                 lastCallnumber = c.getString(0);
                 lastCallnumber=FormatNumber(lastCallnumber);                     
                 String type=c.getString(1);
                 String duration=c.getString(2);
                 String name=c.getString(3);
                 String id=c.getString(4);
                 System.out.println("CALLLLing:"+lastCallnumber+"Type:"+type+"\t id:"+id);
 if(type.equals("3")){
    //you can get last missedcall here
 }
```

You can try it may be helpful for you.